# How to use a stringify JSON data from Yelp API

Tags: javascript, json, stringify, yelp

I am trying to figure out how to use the data in [Yelp API v2](http://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation). How do you read the data given by yelp after you json.stringify it. This is what I did,

```
var output = JSON.stringify(data);
alert(output[0].id) // This comes out to be undefined.
```

How do you read the json data from yelp api?

Comment: Please show how you are creating the `data` variable.

Comment: The result of `JSON.stringify()` is just a string. If you're given JSON and want the object, you call `JSON.parse()`.

Answer (score 0):

`data` should already be an object. `alert(data[0].id)`. If you're grabbing it from `$.ajax`, which I assume, it will return an object.

If `data` is a string, then you want:

```
var output = JSON.parse(data);
alert(output[0].id)
```